EEPROM page size limitation only applies to write instruction?
I want to use the M24C01 EEPROM IC which mentions in its datasheet that page size is 16-byte. But does not state if this is the page size for the read operation as well. (I want to do a sequential read from byte 0 to byte 255, sending the address byte only once, in the beginning).
Though, when it talks about read operations, the M24C01 does not mention limitations on regarding the page size.
Q: Do EEPROM ICs use the page size "limitation" only for the write instruction or it automatically applies for the read instruction?
Other datasheets do mention "Write page size" like the N24C02 IC so the engineer knows that the page only applies to read instruction:


From the M24C01 datasheet section 5.2.3 Sequential read contains the following, with no mention of a page:

The output data comes from consecutive addresses, with the internal address counter automatically incremented after each byte output. After the last memory address, the address counter “rolls-over”, and the device continues to output data from memory address 00h.

The write operations are defined as the following:

Byte Write
Page Write

The read operations are specified as the following, none of which mention page in their name:

Current Address Read
Random Address Read
Sequential Current Read
Sequential Random Read

Therefore, for the M24C01 my interpretation of the datasheet is that the concept of a page implicitly only applies to write operations.

In general, the physical nature of electrically erasable programmable read only memory (EEPROM) can be optimized if the device is allowed to erase entire blocks of memory at a time. So, in many cases, writing and reading are not constrained to the block. But erasing is.
In answer to the question, in most cases, writing to an EEPROM is not constrained to a page (block) of memory.

My question was if reading is constrained in EEPROM due to page size. (Not the writing). So I think you meant "reading" in your last sentence.

The M24C01 datasheet from the question doesn't mention the term erase, and Figure 8. Write cycle polling flowchart using ACK  the internal write cycle hides the details of performing an erase from the I2C bus master.

Interesting, thanks for pointing that out. I wonder if this makes the M24C01 incompatible with a lot of flash memory management drivers. I would have thought such drivers expect a separate block erase feature.

Using the page write buffer means that you can write (a very slow operation that takes  several milliseconds to erase and write the relevant locations) up to 16 bytes as fast as one byte.
If that is not important to you, you can ignore the page structure and just deal with individual bytes, for reading or writing. The sequential read feature does not involve the page structure at all.
